# R: Duplicate entries created with complete sequence

Tags: r

I am filling the data frame for missing months from the current date to past 6 months. However duplicate entries are being created by complete function.

```
data

City    date    year    month
LA  11/1/22 2022    11
LA  12/2/22 2022    12
LA  12/4/22 2022    12
LA  1/4/23  2023    1
LA  1/5/23  2023    1
NY  11/1/22 2022    11
NY  12/2/22 2022    12
NY  12/4/22 2022    12
NY  1/4/23  2023    1
NY  1/5/23  2023    1
OK  11/5/22 2022    11
OK  12/2/22 2022    12
OK  12/4/22 2022    12
OK  1/4/23  2023    1
OK  2/5/23  2023    2
```

This is what i tried

```
Sys.Date() # in this case "2023-04-02"
months6<- data %>%
  filter(date > Sys.Date() %m-% months(5)) %>%
  group_by(City,year, month) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Total_city = n()) 

months6 <- months6 %>%
  mutate(date = make_yearmonth(year,month)) %>%
  select(City, date, Total_city) %>%
  complete(date = seq(min(date), Sys.Date(), by = 1), fill = list(Total_city = 0)) %>%
  group_by(City_Name) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Total_city = n())
```

Expected output:

```
City    date    Total_city
LA  11/2022 1
LA  12/2022 2
LA  1/2023  2
LA  2/2023  0
LA  3/2023  0
LA  4/2023  0
```

Comment: Your "date" field in your data is formatted like 11/1/22, which looks like text and not a Date type variable (which would print as 2022-11-01), and your output looks like "11/22022" which is also not a Date. And yet your code uses syntax made to work on Date data. Have you tried converting it to Date, e.g. `data$date = lubridate::mdy(data$date)`?

Comment: Presumably `Sys.Date()="2023-04-02"` means "run `Sys.Date()` and let's presume the output were 2023-04-02 because we ran it a few weeks ago"? I don't think the code as provided is syntactical.

Comment: yes, it was from a few weeks ago.